# How to properly serve my Angular application static files from a Django project on Heroku?

Tags: django, angular, heroku, django-rest-framework, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy on Heroku my app built with Django 2, DRF and Angular 6, and struggling to get the static files of my Angular app served. I am using WhitheNoise for both development environment and on Heroku.
The structure of the project is as follows:

```
my_project/ 
   |-frontend/
   |    |- dist/
   |    |- ...
   |-myproject/
   |    |-settings/
   |    |  |- __init.py
   |    |  |- base.py
   |    |  |- prod.py
   |    |  |- dev.py
   |    |- __init__.py
   |    |- urls.py
   |    |- views.py
   |    |- wsgi.py
   |-other_app1/
   |    |- ...
   |-other_app2/
   |    |- ...
   |-staticfiles/
   |    |-....
   |-manage.py
   |-Procfile
   |-requirements.txt
```

I have configured Heroku in such a way that every time my app is deployed, my angular app is built, so the static files are generated in frontend/dist/, then collectstatic is run and copies them to my static files folder in the root of my project. My settings are:

```
ANGULAR_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/dist')

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ('frontend', os.path.join(ANGULAR_APP_DIR)),
]
```

This works fine and collects all the files of my angular app inside staticfiles/  withing a folder called frontend/

My problem is that now I am trying to serve the index.html file that is located in staticfiles/frontend and I cannot make it work:

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [      
    path('', HomePageView.as_view()), #first one
    # .... Other urls
]

views.py

from django.views import static

# Serves the index page
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
  def get(self, request, **kwargs):
      return static.serve(request,'index.html', 'staticfiles')
```

This finds and serves the index.html file, but fails to serve successfully the rest of necessary js files for my app to run (polyfills, main, styles...), as the '/static/' is not appended automatically to the url that requests them. 
Does someone know how I can tell Django or Heroku to find them under the staticfiles/frontend folder?

The generated index.html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Angular Project</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.578ada0b0e3742b4b4bb.css"></head>
<body class="with-top-navbar">
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.92d800a8cdfd75f49eae.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.4aeccc46b72bbab58fd0.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

And the output of my console is:

```
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 638
Not Found: /styles.578ada0b0e3742b4b4bb.css
Not Found: /runtime.92d800a8cdfd75f49eae.js
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:30] "GET /styles.578ada0b0e3742b4b4bb.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2353
Not Found: /polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js
Not Found: /main.4aeccc46b72bbab58fd0.js
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:30] "GET /polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2359
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:30] "GET /runtime.92d800a8cdfd75f49eae.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2353
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:30] "GET /main.4aeccc46b72bbab58fd0.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2344
Not Found: /styles.578ada0b0e3742b4b4bb.css
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:32] "GET /styles.578ada0b0e3742b4b4bb.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2353
Not Found: /runtime.92d800a8cdfd75f49eae.js
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:32] "GET /runtime.92d800a8cdfd75f49eae.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2353
Not Found: /polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:32] "GET /polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2359
Not Found: /main.4aeccc46b72bbab58fd0.js
[29/Jun/2018 13:31:32] "GET /main.4aeccc46b72bbab58fd0.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2344
```

Also, please note that I do not want to edit manually the generated index.html nor place it somewhere else, as this would change my deployment workflow.

In addition, I know that django.views.statics.serve is not appropriate for production, so tips are also welcome if you know how to serve this file in some other way

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I could solve it myself by installing this nice package: [django-spa](https://github.com/metakermit/django-spa) that builds on top of whitenoise to serve index and files from a SPA directly from the statics files root folder.

Example of usage of the package [here](https://github.com/metakermit/generator-django-rest)

Also, I had to remove the "frontend" folder from the directory where static filles are collected:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(ANGULAR_APP_DIR),
]
```

And Remove the view I was using to serve my index on '/':

```
urlpatterns = [
  # The following SPA settings are handled in Django-SPA
  # - everything not matched in Django's urlpatterns goes to /
  # - index.html served on /
  # - all /static/... files served on /...
  # other views....
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Thanks to [@metakermit](https://github.com/metakermit) for the package!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am facing the same issue right now. I followed manual and still then I request '/' page I got PageNotFound. Did you do any specific changes in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `render`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

For static files, you need to add `/static/` like

```
{% load static %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "polyfills.7ee4ee2275a8c5d5ea6f.js" %}"></script>
```

Comment: render requires that my index.html is under some template folder, and mine is not. Also, I don't want to edit the index manually, unless it´s the only way

Answer (score 0):

If you're not into using a package, you can try the following

---

`settings.py`

```
ANGULAR_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'path/to/your/angular/app/dist')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(ANGULAR_APP_DIR),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = os.environ.get('STATICFILES_STORAGE', "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage")

WHITENOISE_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
WHITENOISE_INDEX_FILE = True
```

---

Steps:

1. `ng build`
2. `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear`
3. `python manage.py runserver`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560640/django-serving-static-files-angularjs-app)

Answer (score 0):

or you can try to create urls for the javascript / css files

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view()),
    re_path('^(main|polyfills|runtime)\.[a-z0-9]{16}\.js$',get_static),
    re_path('^styles\.[a-z0-9]{16}\.css$',get_static),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py

```
    class HomePageView(TemplateView):
      def get(self, request, **kwargs):
          return static.serve(request,'index.html', settings.ANGULAR_DIR_NAME)


def get_static(request,match=None):
  try:
    file = open(path.join(settings.ANGULAR_APP_DIR,request.path[1:]),'rb')
  except:
    return HttpResponseNotFound()
  content_type = 'text/css' if match is None  else  'text/javascript'
  return HttpResponse(file,content_type='text/javascript')
```